# ldap - find out details of a user

Tags: ldap

One of my clients wants to know why a user can not log in to the portal.

The portal uses the client's LDAP.

Is there a tool/command to run against their Active Directory which will spit out details of the configured user such as permissions/granted hosts and etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you looking for?

- An API do to this in a programming environment? If so: **which one**??
- A Windows command-line tool? There's [Joeware's ADFind](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/adfind/index.htm) - part of a whole suite of free AD tools - which is quite amazing - check it out!